# What is endpoint for oauth2_access_token for linkedin posting a job API?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, 2-legged

Does LinkedIn support OAuth 2.0 grant_type "client_credential" rather than "authorization_code" for closed API? i.e. does LinkedIn support OAuth 2.0 fully?

What is the endpoint for get oauth2_access_token? e.g. https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken

What is the endpoint for posting a job using OAuth 2.0? e.g.
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/jobs

In our case (2-legged OAuth 2.0), we don't need user's authorization/involvement, no nounce, no signature, neither the redirect_url. we simple exchange client_id, client_secret for oauth2_access_token.

I have seen the 1-legged OAuth 1.0 php implementation from LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is no.

LinkedIn doesn't support OAuth 2.0 two-legged implementation at the moment.
grant_type of "authorization_code" is the only type of implementation for three-legged OAuth 2.0 that LinkedIn got at this stage.